# How to use mysqldiff when the database user requires a password?

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql databases that I want to run a diff on, the user I want to connect with (root) has a password.
when I use the command given in mysqldiff documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldiff.html):

```
mysqldiff --server1=root@localhost --server2=root@localhost --difftype=sql old_db:db_brand_new
```

I get an error saying that my command is unauthorized.
I have tried variations on the normal `-p` switch but it doesnt work.
How can I authenticate the `mysqldiff` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked says:

```
--server1=<source>

Connection information for the first server in the format: <user>[:<passwd>]@<host>[:<port>][:<socket>] or <login-path>[:<port>][:<socket>].

--server2=<source>

Connection information for the second server in the format: <user>[:<passwd>]@<host>[:<port>][:<socket>] or <login-path>[:<port>][:<socket>].
```

so you can try
mysqldiff --server1=root:[YOURPASSWORDHERE]@localhost --server2=root:[YOURPASSWORDHERE]@localhost --difftype=sql old_db:db_brand_new

Comment: This stores the password in the shell command history. This is BAD.